# When placed in ui:composition, p:submenu fades out on click of p:megaMenu and aren't clickable on mouseover

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I use the p:megaMenu for menus. p:megaMenu well work without using `<ui:composition>`. 
When i use the p:megaMenu in `<ui:composition>` , the submenu doesn't work well. When click the megamenu the submenu are faded out and when mouseover the submenu, the menu are faded in and can't click. Why?
Somebody answer me plz.

**Here is my page**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:form id="menuForm" >
        <p:megaMenu autoDisplay="false">
            <p:menuitem value="Dashboard" action="dashboard" ajax="false" immediate="true" />
            <p:submenu label="home" >
                <p:column>
                    <p:submenu label="Survey Question">
                        <p:menuitem value="Survey Question" action="manageSurveyQuestion" ajax="false" immediate="true"  />
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>
            </p:submenu>
        </p:megaMenu>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any template file? It is missing `template` in `ui:composition` tag.

```
<ui:composition .... template="/yourtempalte.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="xxxx">      <--- It is optional

  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```